# Still cannot fix "error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist" in Windows 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, javac

UPDATE:  I FOUND MY PROBLEM!!!  The command line command needed to have double quotes around the path to the servlet-api.jar, with the % removed as well.  GAH!!!

I am still getting the dreaded `error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist`

I have read ad nauseam all the other threads about fixing this error and have attempted multiple remedies to no avail.  I'm at the point where I'm hoping someone with a better set of eyes than me spots my typo and calls me out on it!

I have set environment vars to point straight to the `jre7` and the `tomcat` instance:

> C:\JavaProject1>echo %JAVA_HOME% -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;
>
> C:\JavaProject1>echo %CATALINA_HOME% -> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0

I have also added paths pointing directly to servlet-api.jar in both the PATH and CLASSPATH variables.

My command line command:

```
javac -classpath C:\Program%Files\Apache%Software%Foundation\Tomcat%7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar -d classes src\Ch1servlet.java
```

I cannot use `%CATALINA_HOME%` in the command line as the spaces in the directory structure give a false flag at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You should set classpath but not the path for any jar file or any individual classes

Use this command to set ur classpath:

set classpath="your servlet-api.jar path"

and compile the classes

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes for the address. ie, -classpath "path/to/jar/files"
CMD can handle spaces if you put them in double quotes